# Can't filter redis tags in Datadog APM

Tags: datadog, apm

The datadog documentation is severely unclear and lacking in some aspects of APM configuration, specifically when working with something like redis.

I'm trying to filter out a specific redis statement from my trace agent using the `DD_APM_FILTER_TAGS_REJECT` env var. One of the issues seems to be the whitespace in the statement. I can't figure out the proper syntax and I can't find *any* examples online. This is what the trace looks like in the GUI:

[image]

The documentation makes a note of a remapping between `db.statement` and `redis.command` when dropping spans based on tags at the agent level ([source](https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/guide/ignoring_apm_resources/?tab=datadogyaml#database)), however i've tried both and neither have done any filtering.

The photo from the GUI above would suggest that I should configure it as such:

```
- name: DD_APM_FILTER_TAGS_REJECT
  value: "[\"db.statement:RPOP download_queue\"]"
```

but this does not work.

I am using agent `(v7.40.1)` so there should definitely be support for the stringified JSON format I'm using for the env var.

Comment: just to eliminate any potential config or syntax issues, can you filter by other tags?

Comment: @bwest yes, so i originally had this env var set to `"[\"flask.url_rule:/\",\"redis.command:RPOP download_queue\"]"` and the flask filtering was working fine